# RainbowCodeGeneration does not work for Sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore

Could you please advise on the following issue?

I've installed Sitecore 9, Unicorn and Rainbow, items are synced. 
However, when I try to add the latest RainbowCodeGeneration to my project,
after setting up default .tt template, it fails with exception:

```
Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

at the following line:

```
var templates = RainbowCodeGeneration.RainbowReader.GetTemplates(physicalFileStore, treeName, treePath);
```

I use the following configuration:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<# // NOTE - Reference your NuGet packages for Rainbow and RainbowCodeGeneration here #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Rainbow.Core.2.0.0\lib\net452\Rainbow.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Rainbow.Storage.Yaml.2.0.0\lib\net452\Rainbow.Storage.Yaml.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\RainbowCodeGeneration.0.2.0\lib\net452\RainbowCodeGeneration.dll" #>
<# // NOTE - Reference your Sitecore.Kernel.dll and Sitecore.Logging.dll here #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Sitecore.Kernel.9.0.171002\lib\net462\Sitecore.Kernel.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Sitecore.Logging.9.0.171002\lib\net462\Sitecore.Logging.dll" #>
```

Comment: Do you have Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions nuget package added to your solution?

Comment: Adding package itself didn't help

Answer (score 1):

After I've posted this issue on RainbowCodeGeneration project github, version 0.3 was created. It supports Sitecore 9 now.

https://github.com/heikof/RainbowCodeGeneration/issues/4